# how to avoid NSCD for DNS

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

I am using NSCD service for DNS now. But sometimes I see NSCD dying itself and DNS resolving doesn't happen properly. please tell me how can we avoid NSCD for DNS . if we bypass the NSCD what is the dis-advantage ?

Comment: Please let us know, what exactly the issue, if possible update screen-shots

Comment: Why would it be a problem for hosts and not for the other databases (passwd, group, services...)?

Answer (score 8):

When resolving a user, group, host, service..., the process will first try to connect to the `nscd` socket (something like `/var/run/nscd/socket`), I don't think there's a way around that.

If `nscd` has died, the connect will fail, and so nscd won't be used and that should not be a problem.

If it's in a hung state, then the connect may hang or succeed. If it succeeds the client will send its request (give me IP addresses for `www.google.com`, give me passwd entries for `niranjan`...).

Now, you can configure `nscd` (at least the one that comes with the GNU libc) to disable caching for any type of database (for instance by having `enable-cache hosts no` in `/etc/nscd.conf` for the `hosts` database).

In that case, `nscd` will reply to the client: *I don't do caching* and the client will do the resolution by itself.

However, if `nscd` is in a *hung* state, it may not be able to even give that simple *won't do* answer, so that won't necessarily help. But that's probably the closer to what you want you will get short of disabling `nscd` altogether.

`nscd` is a caching daemon, it's meant to improve performance. Disabling it would potentially make those look ups slower. However that's only true for some kind of databases. For instance if your user/service/group databases are only in small files (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/services`), then using `nscd` for those will probably bring little benefit if any. `nscd` will be useful for the `hosts` database. But then instead of using `nscd`, you could also use a local caching DNS server like `dnsmasq` instead.

Comment: Thank u so much stephane, info is very useful and I appreciate ur timely help ...